# Liferay - theme across all portlets?

Tags: liferay, theming

If I create multiple portlets with liferay, how can I have 1 theme control the look of all of them?

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow your question. This should be as simple as using the CSS in your theme to style all of these portlets, deploying, and using your theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Liferay's templating system consists of Velocity/Freemarker templates that renders particular html segments of portlets on a page. It is essentially one theme that styles everything.

If you choose to use JSPs on server side and Alloy UI framework on client side, even your portlet would have the same look and feel as the rest of the portal because Liferay JSP taglibs and Alloy UI both use the same CSS classes that the classic/default Liferay theme is expecting and made for.